# Floating point exception C. Why?

Tags: c, floating-point

I wrote a simple code in C about the traffic of cash register, but I always get "Floating point exception". I know, it's happen at overflow and dividing by zero, but I think at this case contain none of these. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int kassza[32] = {0};
    int a;
    int ossz = 0;

    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("meg ok");

    while (a != 0) 
    {
        kassza[a - 1]++;
        ossz++;
        scanf("%d", &a);
    }

    int max = 0;
    for (int a = 1; a < 32; a++)
    {
        if (kassza[a] > kassza[max]) 
        {
            max = a;
        }
    }
    printf("%d. kassza: %d %%-a az osszes vevonek\n", max + 1, kassza[max], kassza[max] / (ossz / 100));
    return 0;
}
```

so idk why this,pls help me!

Comment: This usually happens when you divide by zero. The only division I see is by `ossz/100`. So I guess it is zero (which is very likely as it is an *integer* division).

Comment: Rewrite the last printf argument to kasua[max]*100/ossz

Comment: Side note: Avoid long statements like the one containing `printf()`. Try to simplify it so that it doesn't confuse you or anyone else later on.

Comment: Unless `ossz` reaches at least 100, your division by `(ossz / 100)` is equivalent to '(integer) divide by zero' — which is just about the only reason you get a 'floating point exception' these days.  Floating point operations, even divisions by zero, don't usually generate a floating point exception but rather an infinity.

Comment: It would help if you could indicate on which line the error happens. If your error message doesn't say, then use a debugger to find out.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: unless something sets or resets certain flags, like e.g. some DLLs do in Windows, and perhaps other code on other platforms too.

Answer (score 0):

Code incurs division by zero due to `kassza[max] / (ossz / 100)` and `ossz < 100`.

In that case, `ossz/100` --> 0 due to integer division and then `kassza[max] / 0` is division by zero.

Integer division by 0 is often (mis-)reported as a *Floating point exception*.